# How do i press this button

Tags: vb.net

So, i have been working on a simple task but i've been running into some problems. I found out that i can't use element id's so i went with just nailing down the elements by searching though the tag name and then search for a keyword. But even then i ran into a problem. Im not sure what to do now.

```
        Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

            If e.Url.AbsolutePath <> TryCast(sender, WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath Then
                Return
            End If
            For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("LI")
                If elem.InnerText = "Gange med 0" Then
                    elem.InvokeMember("click")
                End If

            Next
            For Each elem2 As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON")
                If elem2.!!PROBLEM IS HERE!! = "go" Then
                    elem2.InvokeMember("click")
                End If
            Next



        End Sub
```

Ive tried with Outer- and innerhtml, ive also tried with text, but i cant seem to figure it out

This is the button i need to press
[This is the button](http://pastebin.com/s9eEtdZa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try matching against the `class` attribute:

```
If elem2.GetAttribute("className") = "big primary actionButton" Then
    elem2.InvokeMember("click")
End If
```

Comment: @Frankthatimout : Are you sure you matched against "**className**" and not just "class"?

Comment: Thanks a whole lot! I got it to work my mistake was last time when i tried it, i didnt specify the attribute and didnt really think about it.

Comment: @Frankthatimout : Glad I could help!